# Combine images into single image

Tags: coronasdk

How can I combine two PNGs into one image?

If one image is displays "1", and another image displays "9" - I'd like make an image file showing "19".

There is a object "group" which group the images into an array, but it doesn't seem that I can merge the members of a group.

Comment: Visually, a group would suffice for displaying the two as one "image". What else do you need it to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 = display.newImage( "number1.png" );
number9 = display.newImage( "number9.png" );

number19 = display.newGroup();
number19:insert(number1)
number19:insert(number9)

--Put 9 next to 1
number9.left =number1.width
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a `snapshot` when I need to combine images. Very similar to a group, the snapshot can be rendered out as a single PNG or JPEG.

```
local Function MakeSnapshot()
    local snapshot = display.newSnapshot(digitWidth*2, digitWidth)  
    local digit1 = display.newImage("number1.png")
    local digit2 = display.newImage("number9.png")

    digit1:translate(-digitWidth/2, 0)
    digit2:translate(digitWidth/2, 0)

    snapshot.group:insert(digit1)
    snapshot.group:insert(digit2)
    snapshot:invalidate()

    --Save file as a single image:
    display.save(snapshot, "19.png", system.DocumentsDirectory)
end
```